# wget output based on regex

Tags: regular-expression, wget

I have a very long list of files in the following format:

```
https://server.com/Nonsense%20text%20Actual%20Filename01.ext<br>
https://server.com/Non%20essential%20text%20Actual%20Filename02.ext<br>
https://server.com/Not%20required%20text%20Actual%20Filename03.ext<br>
```

Question is how to apply regex to wget -O so only the pattern on the right, or certain amount of characters on the right result in the output-files?

```
wget https://server.com/Non%20essential%20text%20Actual%20Filename02.ext -O Actual Filename02.ext
```

Comment: What is the common ground for `Nonsense%20text%20`'s and the other text, can you give a real example ?

Comment: Just random words, with no numbers, therefore the excessive parts form only of alphabets.

Comment: can you provide a real example with 10-20 links ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, that's the best I can do, however, the example links `<br>`-html-tag is just editing for stackexchange, otherwise examples do not deviate in structure from the real ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a function, i.e.:

```
function dl() {
  URL="$1"
  NAME=$(egrep -io 'filename[0-9]{1,2}\.ext' <<< "$URL")
  echo wget -O "$NAME" "$URL"
}
```

Now you can use your `dl` function:

```
$ for url in $(cat url_list.txt); do dl $url; done
wget -O Filename01.ext https://server.com/Nonsense%20text%20Actual%20Filename01.ext<br>
wget -O Filename02.ext https://server.com/Non%20essential%20text%20Actual%20Filename02.ext<br>
wget -O Filename03.ext https://server.com/Not%20required%20text%20Actual%20Filename03.ext<br>
```